# Hiding a CSS class using PHP in Wordpress Woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, class, woocommerce

I'm no programmer, I really don't understand anything at all. I'm using this code using the **Snippets Plugin** for Wordpress to hide the **Add Cart Button** from a single product.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'rudr_remove_add_to_cart_single_product' );
function rudr_remove_add_to_cart_single_product(){
   if( !is_product() ) {
    return;
   }
$product = wc_get_product( get_queried_object_id() );
   if( 354 === $product->get_id() || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
    echo "<style>.single_add_to_cart_button {display: none;}</style>";
   }
}
```

But is not working the way I intent too, I know that if I use the code blow in "**Additional CSS**" section from Wordpress it works, but I saw on several websites that it is not a good practice to do it that way.

```
#product-354 .single_add_to_cart_button {
   display: none;
}
```

I know I could use:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 
30 );
```

But that will hide the extra button I have next to it, I have an "Add Cart Button" and a Button with a Custom Link next to it.

How can I use CSS inside a PHP function to hide that Button on that specific product?
I tried to search for something like this and I did not found it, so I'm sorry if it is a repost.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space after "!"

Before

```
if( ! is_product() ) {
    return;
   }
```

After

```
if( !is_product() ) {
    return;
   }
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it removes both buttons, I just want to remove the Add To Cart Button, not all the buttons on the same section.